# Ckfinder/Connector not found in asp.net MVC ZIP Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am trying to integrate ckfinder with ckeditor in MVC Project.
Both CKfinder and CkEditor Unzip folders copied into Solution Root.
CkEditor works fine. but CkFinder connector gives error when try to click on  Browse Server button.

Urls script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {

        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'

    });
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, '/ckfinder/');

</script>
```

[image]

Can anybody share an easy integration method of ckfinder in MVC?

I also tried to follow all such tutorials

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/integration.html

but have no luck

Comment: on the tutorial there's a `Startup` method being called that has `app.Map("/ckfinder/connector", SetupConnector);` . This should setup the connector at that path.

Comment: That tutorial method is Nuget method. Any how I also Included that Class in my Project. But still same issue.

Comment: It is not enough to drop CKFinder 3 folder into your application like it was in case of CKFinder 2. You either need to install CKFinder as a separate application (from zip) or use NuGet packages to integrate them into your application. Please see: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_installation. I would strongly recommend going for NuGet packages.

Comment: adding startup method gives me this error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463320/cs0103-c-sharp-the-name-configureauth-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context